# Using median instead of mean as aggregation function in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have a dataframe that contains cars, their brand and their price. I would like to replace the `avg` below by `median` (or another percentile):

```
df.groupby('carBrand').agg(F.avg('carPrice').alias('avgPrice'))
```

However, it seems that there is no aggregation function that allows to compute this in Spark.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the approxQuantile function (see http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions)